# Python Algorithms for smoothing / discarding bad points in graph

Tags: python, graph, interpolation, gaussian, nonlinear-optimization

I have some graphs with points that are inaccurate readings, but you see where the points should be

[image]

I'm looking for a way to create a really smooth graph, maybe even if there is a way create a nonlinear equation from the points

I've tried some interpolation algos but they didn't get rid of the bad points
(make_interp_spline, convolve, gaussian)

Comment: You may want to use a polynomial regression to compute f(x) where x > 45

Comment: Thanks! Y axis is not known in advance and the bed readings are not known in advance as well, is there a algo to find them?

Comment: I was looking further, it's an interesting problem. You can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598986/reducing-noise-on-data